# Why is a TypeConverterAttribute not used in DataBinding?

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, typeconverter

I've spent about a day trying to figure out why one particular class was not making use of the TypeConverters marked on its properties.

It turns out it wasn't the class itself, but the fact that I'd created a manual databinding to the UI where I normally use an extension method.

So, before you go chasing "AssemblyResolve" or "use the type name instead of typeof", if your problem involves databinding, check this.

Answer (score 0):

```
txt.DataBindings.Add(nameof(txt.Text), source, propertyName, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, null, format);  //WORKS
txt.DataBindings.Add(nameof(txt.Text), source, propertyName, false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, null, format);  //fails
txt.DataBindings.Add(nameof(txt.Text), source, propertyName);  //fails
```

That true/false flag there?

That's "formattingEnabled".